French movie where a kid sells his brother
I remember a movie I saw about a young boy in France who thinks that his mother is pregnant after mishearing an exchange between his parents. He starts to think that his parents won't love him and plots to get rid of the baby. Him and his friends try to raise enough money to get rid of the baby. But his parents tell him that he was wrong before he gets enough. Some years later, his parents actually do get pregnant but he tells them that he would rather have a puppy than a sibling.
Other details:

Originally in French, but had English subtitles
Made in the late 2000s (2007-2009)

That's all, folks!

It is Le Petit Nicolas (2009)
The boy (Nicholas) overhears a conversation in a dinner party that leads him to believe that his mother is pregnant. His friends then tell him that having a sibling is terrible as your parents abandon you. Him and his friends try to raise 500 francs to take the baby to the jungle and leave it there. However, before he can raise enough, his parents realise what has happened and tell him the truth, which upsets him a great deal because he had discovered how nice it is to have a sibling.
Eventually, his mother does actually become pregnant and Nicholas is overjoyed. Yet when the baby is born and it turns out to be a girl, he tells his parents that he'd rather have a puppy.
